# GLIBC_2.28 not found (required by ./fabric-ca-server)

Tags: linux, shell, hyperledger-fabric, bin, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I try to initialize Fabric CA server by command:

```
./fabric-ca-server init -b {user}:{password}
```

and receive:

```
./fabric-ca-server: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by ./fabric-ca-server)
```

I read that updating of GLIBC_2.28 is risky.
Help me please.

Comment: That error message means your binary was not built for your system. There are a variety of ways this can be addressed, but generally speaking you should probably upgrade your *whole* system *and keep it up-to-date*, if for nothing else but security reasons alone. (If you need to *update* to GLIBC_2.28, you are in trouble -- that version is *ancient*.) And use the binary appropriate for your (version of your) system. Trying to "patch around" issues like these will only get you into yet more trouble.

Comment: @DevSolar Where can i find binaries matching my version? Why is it now in the hyperledger/fabric-samples repo bin files missing?

Comment: What is your system, and system's version? What is the version of Hyperledger Fabric that you're trying to work with?

Comment: @DevSolar 
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64

Hyperledger Fabric v1.0.0

Comment: Hyperledger Fabric v1.0.0... what is your reasoning there? Unless I am *really* confusing things here, [from the docs](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric#releases), v1.4.x has been discontinued in April 2021, and the current LTS version is 2.2.x...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fabric-ca-server binaries are built on Ubuntu. The version of Ubuntu that was used will depend on the version of fabric-ca-server you are trying to use.

Whatever version of fabric-ca-server you are trying to run it won't run on your version of linux due fabric-ca-server now requiring a specific capability that is in GLIBC_2.28 or higher.

If you need a specific version of fabric-ca-server running on a specific distribution and version of linux you will need to clone the github repo for fabric-ca (checkout the appropriate tag for the version you want) and build the code yourself with the correct version of the GoLang compiler and other dependencies.